# Oracle SQL : distinct count with group by cube

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle12c

**My objective :**

I want to distinctly count every possible combinations by using a group by cube.

**The query I use :**

```
select         col_3,
                col_4, 
                col_5, 
                col_6,
                col_7, 
                col_8,
                col_9,
                count(distinct col_1)    count_distinct
from            tmp_test_data
group           by cube (
                         col_3,
                         col_4,
                         col_5,
                         col_6,
                         col_7,
                         col_8,
                         col_9
                        )
order by        col_3,
                col_4,
                col_5,
                col_6,
                col_7,
                col_8,
                col_9
                ;
```

**Example data** (complete table has 100K rows) :

```
col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 count_distinct   
2    3    1    1    1    1    1    12
2    3    1    1    1    1         12
2    3    1    1    1    2    1    1
2    3    1    1    1    2    2    8
2    3    1    1    1    2         9
2    3    1    1    1         1    13
2    3    1    1    1         2    8
2    3    1    1    1              21
...
```

**The problem I am facing :** 
Using count(distinct col_1) affects the performance of the query (~10 minutes), whereas count(col1) is pretty fast (~10 seconds).
When checking the explain plan it appears that the distinct count forces 64 'group by rollup'

**Explain plan :**

count(col1)

```
Plan hash value: 3126999781
| Id  | Operation            | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |

|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |               |   288 |  8640 |  1316   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY       |               |   288 |  8640 |  1316   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   GENERATE CUBE      |               |   288 |  8640 |  1316   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    SORT GROUP BY     |               |   288 |  8640 |  1316   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| TMP_TEST_DATA |   668K|    19M|  1296   (1)| 00:00:01 |
```

count(distinct col_1

```
Plan hash value: 1939696204

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                            |   288 | 29952 | 50234   (4)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION |                            |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9E9C98_2ACFFE0 |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL       | TMP_TEST_DATA              |   668K|    19M|  1296   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |   LOAD AS SELECT           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9E9C9A_2ACFFE0 |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |    SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP    |                            |   288 |  8640 |   765   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | SYS_TEMP_0FD9E9C98_2ACFFE0 |   668K|    19M|   745   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |   LOAD AS SELECT           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9E9C9A_2ACFFE0 |       |       |            |          |
|   8 |    SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP    |                            |   204 |  6120 |   765   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | SYS_TEMP_0FD9E9C98_2ACFFE0 |   668K|    19M|   745   (1)| 00:00:01 |
...
| 190 |   LOAD AS SELECT           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9E9C9A_2ACFFE0 |       |       |            |          |
| 191 |    SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP    |                            |     3 |    90 |   765   (4)| 00:00:01 |
| 192 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | SYS_TEMP_0FD9E9C98_2ACFFE0 |   668K|    19M|   745   (1)| 00:00:01 |
| 193 |   LOAD AS SELECT           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9E9C9A_2ACFFE0 |       |       |            |          |
| 194 |    SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP    |                            |     2 |    60 |   765   (4)| 00:00:01 |
| 195 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | SYS_TEMP_0FD9E9C98_2ACFFE0 |   668K|    19M|   745   (1)| 00:00:01 |
| 196 |   SORT ORDER BY            |                            |   288 | 29952 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
| 197 |    VIEW                    |                            |   288 | 29952 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 198 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | SYS_TEMP_0FD9E9C9A_2ACFFE0 |   288 |  8640 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to improve this ?

Comment: Why do you need the order by if you are just trying to get counts? The order by slows you down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

No, I do not see a way to improve this, if you really need exact `count_distinct` results.

If you can live with an approximation, then using the function [APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions013.htm#SQLRF56900) might be an option.

```
select          col_3,
                col_4, 
                col_5, 
                col_6,
                col_7, 
                col_8,
                col_9,
                approx_count_distinct(col_1)    approx_count_distinct
from            t
group           by cube (
                         col_3,
                         col_4,
                         col_5,
                         col_6,
                         col_7,
                         col_8,
                         col_9
                        )
order by        col_3,
                col_4,
                col_5,
                col_6,
                col_7,
                col_8,
                col_9
                ;
```

## Longer Answer

I created this test table

```
CREATE TABLE t AS
SELECT round(abs(dbms_random.normal)*10,0) AS col_1,
       round(dbms_random.VALUE(2,3),0) AS col_3,
       round(dbms_random.VALUE(3,4),0) AS col_4,
       round(dbms_random.VALUE(1,2),0) AS col_5,
       round(dbms_random.VALUE(1,2),0) AS col_6,
       round(dbms_random.VALUE(1,2),0) AS col_7,
       round(dbms_random.VALUE(1,2),0) AS col_8,
       round(dbms_random.VALUE(1,2),0) AS col_9
  FROM xmltable('1 to 20000');
```

set the statistics_level to `ALL` to gather detailed execution plan statistics

```
ALTER SESSION SET statistics_level = 'ALL';
```

executed the original query on table `t` instead of `tmp_test_data`

```
select          col_3,
                col_4, 
                col_5, 
                col_6,
                col_7, 
                col_8,
                col_9,
                count(distinct col_1)    count_distinct
from            t
group           by cube (
                         col_3,
                         col_4,
                         col_5,
                         col_6,
                         col_7,
                         col_8,
                         col_9
                        )
order by        col_3,
                col_4,
                col_5,
                col_6,
                col_7,
                col_8,
                col_9
                ;
```

to produced this result

```
     COL_3      COL_4      COL_5      COL_6      COL_7      COL_8      COL_9 COUNT_DISTINCT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------
         2          3          1          1          1          1          1             27
         2          3          1          1          1          1          2             24
         2          3          1          1          1          1                        31
...
                                                                           2             40
                                                                                         41

2.187 rows selected.
```

and this execution plan.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                |Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |     1 |        |   2187 |00:00:01.85 |      87 |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION               |     1 |        |   2187 |00:00:01.85 |      87 |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)|     1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.07 |      86 |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                         |     1 |    464 |   3224 |00:00:00.02 |      85 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                    |     1 |  20000 |  20000 |00:00:00.01 |      85 |
|   5 |   SORT ORDER BY                          |     1 |     16 |   2187 |00:00:01.77 |       0 |
|   6 |    VIEW                                  |     1 |    408 |   2187 |00:00:01.75 |       0 |
|   7 |     VIEW                                 |     1 |    408 |   2187 |00:00:01.73 |       0 |
|   8 |      UNION-ALL                           |     1 |        |   2187 |00:00:01.72 |       0 |
|   9 |       SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP               |     1 |     16 |    192 |00:00:00.03 |       0 |
...
| 133 |       SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP               |     1 |      3 |      6 |00:00:00.03 |       0 |
| 134 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                 |     1 |    464 |   3224 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
| 135 |       SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP               |     1 |      2 |      3 |00:00:00.02 |       0 |
| 136 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                 |     1 |    464 |   3224 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Interesting is the column `A-Rows` (actual number of rows) `A-Time` (actual amount of time spent) and `Buffers` (number of logical reads). We see that the query took 1.85 seconds for 87 logical I/Os. All 64 `SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP` took 1.75 seconds, that's about 0.03 seconds per operation. Oracle needs to evaluate the number of distinct values of col_1 for each group-by-combination. There is no shortcut as in `COUNT(col_1)`. That's why it is costly.

However, we could easily come up with an alternative query

```
WITH
   combi AS (
      SELECT col_3, 
             col_4, 
             col_5, 
             col_6, 
             col_7, 
             col_8, 
             col_9
        FROM t
       GROUP BY CUBE (
                   col_3, 
                   col_4, 
                   col_5, 
                   col_6, 
                   col_7, 
                   col_8, 
                   col_9
                )
   ),
   fullset AS (
      SELECT t.col_1,
             combi.col_3, 
             combi.col_4, 
             combi.col_5, 
             combi.col_6, 
             combi.col_7, 
             combi.col_8, 
             combi.col_9
        FROM combi
        JOIN t
          ON     (t.col_3 = combi.col_3 or combi.col_3 is null)
             AND (t.col_4 = combi.col_4 or combi.col_4 is null)
             AND (t.col_5 = combi.col_5 or combi.col_5 is null)
             AND (t.col_6 = combi.col_6 or combi.col_6 is null)
             AND (t.col_7 = combi.col_7 or combi.col_7 is null)
             AND (t.col_8 = combi.col_8 or combi.col_8 is null)
             AND (t.col_9 = combi.col_9 or combi.col_9 is null)
   )
SELECT col_3, 
       col_4, 
       col_5, 
       col_6, 
       col_7, 
       col_8, 
       col_9,
       COUNT(DISTINCT col_1) as count_distinct_col_1
  FROM fullset
 GROUP BY col_3, 
          col_4, 
          col_5, 
          col_6, 
          col_7, 
          col_8, 
          col_9
 ORDER BY col_3, 
          col_4, 
          col_5, 
          col_6, 
          col_7, 
          col_8, 
          col_9;
```

producing the same result

```
     COL_3      COL_4      COL_5      COL_6      COL_7      COL_8      COL_9 COUNT_DISTINCT_COL_1
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
         2          3          1          1          1          1          1                   27
         2          3          1          1          1          1          2                   24
         2          3          1          1          1          1                              31
...
                                                                           2                   40
                                                                                               41

2.187 rows selected.
```

with fewer lines in the execution plan.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name      | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |           |      1 |        |   2187 |00:00:41.58 |     185K|
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY            |           |      1 |     16 |   2187 |00:00:41.58 |     185K|
|   2 |   VIEW                    | VM_NWVW_1 |      1 |    464 |  67812 |00:00:41.54 |     185K|
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY          |           |      1 |    464 |  67812 |00:00:41.54 |     185K|
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS          |           |      1 |   2500 |   2560K|00:00:31.77 |     185K|
|   5 |      VIEW                 |           |      1 |     16 |   2187 |00:00:00.37 |      85 |
|   6 |       SORT GROUP BY       |           |      1 |     16 |   2187 |00:00:00.36 |      85 |
|   7 |        GENERATE CUBE      |           |      1 |     16 |  16384 |00:00:00.27 |      85 |
|   8 |         SORT GROUP BY     |           |      1 |     16 |    128 |00:00:00.20 |      85 |
|   9 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL| T         |      1 |  20000 |  20000 |00:00:00.10 |      85 |
|* 10 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL    | T         |   2187 |    156 |   2560K|00:00:13.09 |     185K|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Let's look at operation 5. We produce all 2187 combinations within 0.37 seconds and need 85 logical I/Os to read the full table `t`. Then we access the full table `t` again for each of these 2187 combinations (see operation 4 and 10). The complete `join` takes 31.77 seconds. The remaining `group by` operations takes 9.77 seconds and the final `sort` just 0.04. seconds.

This alternative query looks simple, but is much slower due to additional I/O operations necessary for the join of the named queries `combi` and `fullset`.

The original view is better in terms of I/O and runtime. Granted the execution plan looks extensive, but is efficient. In the end the `DISTINCT` in `COUNT(DISTINCT col_1)` is driving the complexity. It's just a word, but a complete different algorithm. Hence, I do not see how to improve the original query, if accurate results are important. However, if an approximation is good enough then using the function [APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions013.htm#SQLRF56900) might be an option.

```
select          col_3,
                col_4, 
                col_5, 
                col_6,
                col_7, 
                col_8,
                col_9,
                approx_count_distinct(col_1)    approx_count_distinct
from            t
group           by cube (
                         col_3,
                         col_4,
                         col_5,
                         col_6,
                         col_7,
                         col_8,
                         col_9
                        )
order by        col_3,
                col_4,
                col_5,
                col_6,
                col_7,
                col_8,
                col_9
                ;
```

The results are similar

```
     COL_3      COL_4      COL_5      COL_6      COL_7      COL_8      COL_9 APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------
         2          3          1          1          1          1          1                    27
         2          3          1          1          1          1          2                    24
         2          3          1          1          1          1                               31
...
                                                                           2                    40
                                                                                                41

2.187 rows selected.
```

but execution plan is even more complex.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |      1 |        |   2187 |00:00:09.88 |      87 |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION               |      1 |        |   2187 |00:00:09.88 |      87 |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)|      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.33 |      86 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                     |      1 |  20000 |  20000 |00:00:00.08 |      85 |
|   4 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)|      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.16 |       0 |
|   5 |    SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP APPROX           |      1 |     16 |    192 |00:00:00.16 |       0 |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                    |      1 |  20000 |  20000 |00:00:00.07 |       0 |
...
| 190 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)|      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.14 |       0 |
| 191 |    SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP APPROX           |      1 |      3 |      6 |00:00:00.14 |       0 |
| 192 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                    |      1 |  20000 |  20000 |00:00:00.07 |       0 |
| 193 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)|      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.14 |       0 |
| 194 |    SORT GROUP BY ROLLUP APPROX           |      1 |      2 |      3 |00:00:00.14 |       0 |
| 195 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                    |      1 |  20000 |  20000 |00:00:00.07 |       0 |
| 196 |   SORT ORDER BY                          |      1 |     16 |   2187 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
| 197 |    VIEW                                  |      1 |     16 |   2187 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
| 198 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                    |      1 |     16 |   2187 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and the query is slower than the original one. It is expected to be faster on large data sets. Therefore, I suggest to try `APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT`, if a 100% accuracy is not required.

#### Runtime Overhead by Statistic_Level `ALL`

To get the actual number of rows and the actual time spent in the execution plan, I've run all queries with statistics_level `ALL`. This lead to a significant performance overhead (that's expected, see also [Jonathan Lewis' blog about gather_plan_staticis](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/11/25/gather_plan_statistics/)). When setting staticstics_level to `TYPICAL` all queries run faster. Here are the runtimes in seconds incl. time for printing result on the client:

```
Query                  Runtime with 'ALL'  Runtime with 'TYPICAL' 
----------------       ------------------  ----------------------
Original (good)                     2.615                   0.977
Alternative (bad)                  41.773                   4.991
Approx_Count_Distinct              10.600                   1.113
```